# $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ is continuous, as well as analytic outside $[-1,1]$; show $f$ is entire

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I need to show that if $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ is continuous with $f$ analytic outside $[-1,1]$ then $f$ is an entire function. I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theorem: if $f(z)$ is analytic on an open rectangle $R$ and continuous on its closure, $\int_{\partial R} f(z) dz = 0$.

Note that Morera's theorem holds for $f$ on on an open connected set $U$ if the integral of $f$ around every rectangle in $U$ (with sides parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axes) is 0 (I can fill in the details if need be). By the above theorem this holds in this case: if you want to integrate $f$ around a rectangle enclosing some part of $[-1, 1]$, you can chop it into several smaller rectangles so that the portion of $[-1, 1]$ being integrated around lies on their boundaries. Thus $f$ satisfies the hypotheses of Morera's theorem and is analytic on $\Bbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy using [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera's_theorem) (in the version that just requires the integral around triangles be $0$).

Comment: @HenningMakholm The integral over a very thin triangle along the line is arbitrarily small, hence by partitioning a triangle crossing the line we can make its integral arbitrarily small, hence it must be zero.

Comment: If you use Green's theorem, then the triangle can be any piecewise-smooth curve.

Comment: I have tried to write the show but I can not clearly express the idea with mathematical notation.How do I describe the integral with respect to these triangles? It can also happen that some triangle does not intersect the line segment. Sorry, I can not see the proof.